# Error starting jpos Q2 server : java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: linux, jpos

I have deployed standalone Q2 server in linux (centos) machine. When starting Q2 server i am getting UnknownHostException. I am unable to figure out which host the Q2 server is referring. I am using channel_adapter, server_config, qserver_mux and txnmgr_config xml based configuration in deploy folder. The same was working till i restarted the service. Please find the extract of q2.log.

```
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="Sun Dec 24 08:22:36 NPT 2017.111">
  <info>
    deploy:/home/cmsadmin/isoserver/deploy/99_sysmon.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="org.jpos.q2.iso.QServer" at="Sun Dec 24 08:22:57 NPT 2017.4">
  <warn>
    error starting service
    <iso-exception>
      org.jpos.core.ConfigurationException: org.jpos.iso.ISOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: jpos.org (java.net.UnknownHostException: jpos.org) (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: jpos.org (java.net.UnknownHostException: jpos.org))
      <iso-exception>
        org.jpos.iso.ISOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: jpos.org (java.net.UnknownHostException: jpos.org)
        <iso-exception>
          java.net.UnknownHostException: jpos.org
          <nested-exception>
          java.net.UnknownHostException: jpos.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager.readFile(GenericPackager.java:180)
    at org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager.setConfiguration(GenericPackager.java:145)
    at org.jpos.q2.QFactory.setConfiguration(QFactory.java:390)
    at org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor.newChannel(ChannelAdaptor.java:221)
    at org.jpos.q2.iso.QServer.newChannel(QServer.java:70)
    at org.jpos.q2.iso.QServer.initServer(QServer.java:78)
    at org.jpos.q2.iso.QServer.startService(QServer.java:108)
    at org.jpos.q2.QBeanSupport.start(QBeanSupport.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.jpos.q2.QFactory.startQBean(QFactory.java:199)
    at org.jpos.q2.Q2.start(Q2.java:464)
    at org.jpos.q2.Q2.deploy(Q2.java:282)
    at org.jpos.q2.Q2.start(Q2.java:183)
    at org.jpos.q2.Q2.main(Q2.java:651)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
          </nested-exception>
          org.jpos.iso.ISOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: jpos.org (java.net.UnknownHostException: jpos.org)
```

Comment: The log says that the host that cannot resolv is jpos.org. For some reason your machine is not able to resolve the jpos.org host to an ip address. You can try pinging it to see if it displays an ip like this: 
$ ping jpos.org
PING jpos.org (52.7.83.125) 56(84) bytes of data.

That host is defined in your channel adapter config file.

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz But id dont find this address jpos.org in my config file.
 `code`<channel-adaptor name='sctca' 
    class="org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor" logger="Q2"> 
 <channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.PADChannel"
 logger="Q2" packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager">
 <property name="host" value="172.25.0.222" /> 
 <property name="port" value="12451" /> 
 <property name="packager-config" value="cfg/pack.xml" /> 
 <property name="timeout" value="300000" />
    <property name="keep-alive" value="true" />
</channel>
 <in>IN</in> 
 <out>OUT</out>
</channel-adaptor>`code`

Comment: Please add more info, including that one, to the question. For instance the content of pack.xml. I guess your problem is the dtd reference that is pointing to jpos.org. "<!DOCTYPE isopackager PUBLIC
        "-//jPOS/jPOS Generic Packager DTD 1.0//EN"
        "http://jpos.org/dtd/generic-packager-1.0.dtd">" and somehow your server cannot resolve it.

Comment: by the way which version of jpos are you running?